# How to specify core project path in Libgdx Project Generator?

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx, dependencies, tween

I am following a tutorial on making a flappy bird with the Libgdx framework.
-http://www.kilobolt.com/day-11-supporting-iosandroid--splashscreen-menus-and-tweening.html

I am currently on the step of adding the Tween Engine Library to my project.

The is the algorithm that the author gave us to do

```
1.Open up the gdx-setup-ui jar, like we did in Day 2. If you need to download that again, click here.
2.Specify the core project path as shown below.
3.Make sure you select "Universal Tween Engine" by clicking the checkbox.
```

And the visual diagram that the author gave us that illustrated this algorithm 
[image]

Here is the UI that I get when I launch the jar file [image]

Where do I find core project path in this updated UI? I assumed it was the destination dialog but when I typed in the path to my project and hit generate, I got a dialog that asked me if I was sure I wanted to overwrite my files(in this case i didn't) What would be the new UI's way of going about this? There wasn't even an option for Tween Engine in the extensions[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone is having a similar issue, I recommend doing what I did and following an alternative guide- https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine

basically, installing the jar file, putting it in the libs directory, and adding dependencies in build.gradle